# ReferenceError 1069 (Adobe AIR with AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

So in my code i have something along the lines of this:

```
var tilemap:Vector.<String>;
tilemap = Vector.<String>(dataString.split("\n"));
```

When i trace this i get the correct results, and i have verified that there is no extra whitespace that could be screwing stuff up. However, later in my code, i try doing something like this:

```
for (var y:int = 0; y < tilemap.length; y++)
    for (var x:int = 0; x < tilemap[y].length; x++)
        trace(tilemap[y].charAt[x]);
```

But i get the following error:

> [Fault] exception, information=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property 0 not found on builtin.as$0.MethodClosure and there is no default value.

What exactly is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was a stupid mistake.

This line:

```
trace(tilemap[y].charAt[x]);
```

Should have been:

```
trace(tilemap[y].charAt(x));
```